# Communication between android tablet using USB

Tags: android, usb

I want to make simple app to transfer 100 MP file from one android tablet to another tablet. Both has ice-cream sandwich and USB host port. How to perform this operation? I can't file simple code to send file from one Tab to another Tab.

Comment: By far the most straightforward methods would be wifi or wifi direct if supported.   This eliminates the need for a special cable, though an access point is required for the first.

Comment: No, without WiFi connection how to do that?